# Replacement for deprecated SQL Server User Defined Type with a bound Rule and Default

Tags: sql, sql-server, deprecated, user-defined-types

We have a User Defined Data Type of YesNo which has an which is an alias for char(1). The type has a bound Rule (must be Y or N) and a Default (N).

The aim of this is that when any of the development team create a new field of type YesNo the rule and default are automatically bound to the new column.

Rules and Defaults have been deprecated and won't be available in <strike>the next</strike> a future version of SQL Server, is there another way to achieve the same functionality?

I should add that I'm aware that I could use CHECK and DEFAULT constraints to replicate the functionality of the bound Rule and Defalut objects, however these would have to be applied at each usage of the type, rather than getting the functionality 'for free' by using a UDT which has a bound Rule and Default.

The post relates to a database that backs an existing application, rather than a new development, so I'm aware that our use of UDT's is less than optimal.

I suspect the answer to the question is 'No', however normally when features are deprecated there's usually an alternative syntax that can be used as a drop in replacement so I wanted to pose the question in-case someone knew of an alternative.

Comment: I think you misread the article. CREATE RULE and CREATE DEFAULT are deprecated in favor of specifying DEFAULTs and CHECK rules inside the CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statements.

Comment: which is where I always declare mine.

Comment: Edit to reflect the correct deprecation timescale.

Comment: @Bill I understand that's what they want me to use, that's the point of my post. Using constraints requires the developer to add the constraints to each table each time the UDT is used, whereas using a UDT with a bound Rule and Default you get that for free each time the type is used, which removes a point of potential human error in our development process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default and check constraints...

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
   col1 int...
   YesNo char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ('N')
                   CONSTRAINT CK_foo_YesNo CHECK (YesNo IN 'Y', 'N'))
   col2 ...
   )
```

Personally, I tend not to use UDTs (last time was SQL Server 6.5 IIRC) because there is no ALTER TYPE in case anything changes...

As for deprecation..

First mentioned in [CREATE RULE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188064%28SQL.90%29.aspx) for SQL Server 2005. So, we were told 6 years and 3 releases ago

For [SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258252%28SQL.80%29.aspx)...

> "Rules, a backward compatibility feature, perform some of the same functions as check constraints. CHECK constraints, created using the CHECK keyword of ALTER or CREATE TABLE, are the preferred, standard way..."

The same applies to [CREATE DEFAULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173565.aspx), the *object* not the *constraint*

That's 11 years ago

Comment: I'd love to get rid UDT's too but in this case they're useful and are part of this particular database which has been around for a long time. I know that I could update each use of the type to have a constraint and a default, however that means applying a constraint and a default each time the type is used, what I was asking is if there is a way of achieving what we have at the moment which is having a type that comes with a default value and that can only accept certain values without anding code at each individual use.

Comment: @Adam Jones: not quite what you want, but have you thought about using non-null bit and changing to Y or N in the client? This way, it's native datatype with "built-in" constraint of only 2 values. Ad interim, you could use a computed column to provide Y or N for reading: you only have to change your writes to bit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's a possibility for the future. At some point i'd like to strip out all the UDT's and changing the YesNo to be a non null bit would be on the TODO list. The question was really a point of curiosity. I'd looked for a 'drop in' replacement for our current functionality and couldn't find anything, I put the question on here in case there was something I'd missed. Unfortunately I suspect the short answer to my question is 'No'.

Answer (score 0):

"Rules and Defaults have been deprecated and won't be available in the next version of SQL Server"

1) As far as I know that is not true. You cannot suddenly break 99.9% of TSQL out there!

2) Also, even if it were true (and I strongly believe it is not), deprecated does not mean removed in the next release, simply that a feature should no longer be used in new code.

Do you have an official link to any such announcement?

User @gbn seems to think I am defending the use of deprecated constructs. I am not.

Comment: [CREATE RULE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188064(SQL.90).aspx) for SQL Server 2005. You've only had 6 years and 3 releases. For [SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258252(SQL.80).aspx)... "Rules, a backward compatibility feature, perform some of the same functions as check constraints. CHECK constraints, created using the CHECK keyword of ALTER or CREATE TABLE, are the preferred, standard way..." That's 11 years...

Comment: Addressing these in your answer: "Do you have an official link to any such announcement?" and "As far as I know that is not true. You cannot suddenly break 99.9% of TSQL out there!". You've had bags of time to adjust...

Comment: @gbn: I have no idea what you are talking about. I'm referring to anything 'deprecated'. I personally don't use Rules. I declare my constraints inline (as I've said elsewhere in this question)

Comment: When OP said "Rules and Defaults have been deprecated.." this refers to rule objects (mentioned in previous comment) and [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173565.aspx) *objects*, not default *constraints* associated with tables which you and I and 99.9%+ of TSQL uses. If you've never used them or didn't know about them then fair enough. MS does provide information on deprecation and discontinued features in BOL, normally with 3 versions notice.

Comment: @gbn: as I said, I'm aware of that. you seem to be picking fault for no reason.

Comment: In that case, I can't see what your answer relates to or the point of it is. If you are aware of Rule and Default objects, and you are aware of deprecations/discontinuations, then your answer does not show this. It sounds you *do* use deprecated objects and are challenging OP about it.

Comment: @gbn: that's not what I'm saying: I would never suggest someone use a deprecated construct. Period.

Comment: Apologies, re-read the MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx and they're listed to be removed in a future version of SQL Server rather than the next version.

Comment: However my original point stands, I know that I can achieve the same functionality on a table by table basis using CHECK and DEFAULT constraints but that relies on the developer manually adding the constraints when a new field is added to the table and that's open to user error.  

My question is there any way of achieving the same functionality as is currently achieved using Rules and Defaults bound to user defined type, i.e. the rule and default come for free when you use the type.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: you said "As far as I know that is not true." to the deprecation and then demand a link. Your comments say otherwise, that you do know. Then you accuse me of picking fault in what you've actually posted as an answer. Again: **What is the point of your answer?**. Before you reply to this comment **read** your own answer.

Comment: *Rules and Defaults have been deprecated **AND** won't be available in the next version of SQL Server*... these actually are TWO statements. First one is undisputively true, as shown in the links that were already provided. However, you are right that the second statement isn't true... *yet*. Still, I can't help but agree with @gbh: your answer is somewhat misleading. It would help to clear it up a bit, just so that readers from the future (such as myself ^_^.) won't get confused.

Answer (score -1):

Xquery is a bit obtuse to use for something this simple. I typically use it for more complex data typing, but it does (I think) answer your question regarding a replacement. Here is how I might implement a parameter as typed xml which must be either true or false. You can extend it to be yes/no or puppy/kitten or whatever you'd like.

```
if schema_id(N'chamomile') is null
  execute (N'create schema chamomile');
go
set nocount on;
go
/*
  All content is licensed as [chamomile] (http://www.katherinelightsey.com/#!license/cjlz) and 
    copyright Katherine Elizabeth Lightsey, 1959-2014 (aka; my life), all rights reserved,
    and as open source under the GNU Affero GPL (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html).
  ---------------------------------------------
*/
if exists
   (select xml_collection_id
    from   sys.xml_schema_collections as true_false
    where  true_false.name = 'true_false'
           and true_false.schema_id = schema_id(N'chamomile'))
  drop xml schema collection [chamomile].[true_false];
go
/*
  --
  -- License
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Katherine E. Lightsey
  http://www.katherinelightsey.com

  All content is copyright Katherine Elizabeth Lightsey, 1959-2014 (aka; my life), all rights reserved, 
  licensed as [chamomile] (http://www.katherinelightsey.com/#!license/cjlz) and copyright Katherine Elizabeth Lightsey, 1959-2014 (aka; my life), all rights reserved, 
    and as open source under the GNU Affero GPL (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html).

  --
  -- to view documentation
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  select objtype
       , objname
       , name
       , value
  from   fn_listextendedproperty (null
                  , 'schema'
                  , 'chamomile'
                  , 'xml schema collection'
                  , 'true_false'
                  , default
                  , default);
*/
create xml schema collection [chamomile].[true_false] as N'<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:chamomile="http://www.katherinelightsey.com/" targetNamespace="http://www.katherinelightsey.com/">

    <xsd:element name="true_false" type="chamomile:true_false_type" />

    <xsd:complexType name="true_false_type">
      <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
          <xsd:attribute name="true_false" type="chamomile:pass_fail_enumeration" default="false" />
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:simpleType name="pass_fail_enumeration">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:NMTOKEN">
      <xsd:enumeration value="true" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="false" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>';
go
declare @true_false xml([chamomile].[true_false]) = N'<chamomile:true_false xmlns:chamomile="http://www.katherinelightsey.com/" true_false="true" />';
if (select @true_false.value(N'(/*/@true_false)[1]', N'[sysname]'))
   = N'true'
  select N'true';
go
declare @true_false xml([chamomile].[true_false]) = N'<chamomile:true_false xmlns:chamomile="http://www.katherinelightsey.com/" true_false="false" />';
go
declare @true_false xml([chamomile].[true_false]) = N'<chamomile:true_false xmlns:chamomile="http://www.katherinelightsey.com/" true_false="not_valid" />';
go
```

Comment: I feel this answer would be improved massively by providing an `CREATE TABLE` example with a typed `xml` column using your `true_false` rule - though of course, using `xml` for the OP's use case is significant overkill, and while SQL Server's support for XML Schema validation in typed-`xml` columns and parameters certainly provides a similar UX to the old `RULE` objects, there's no other real advantages...

Comment: Also, posting AGPL code to SO is contrary to SO's user-agreement [that states our contributions are CC-BY-SA, not AGPL](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).